# Is there a r function to find the cumulative sum/rolling sum of a set of rows

Tags: r

Data frame for example

[image]

I have three variables Salary.W1, Salary.W2 and Salary.W3. What is I'm trying to achieve is a cumultive sum for each row.

Comment: `apply(df,1,cumsum)`.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).